# Programmatically pushing data to Quickbooks Online?

Tags: api, finance, quickbooks, accounting

Our company uses Quickbooks Online to track our books. When our application bills a customer, it would be nice to have that information recorded automatically in QB rather than logging in to QB Online to fill in the info.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Quickbook's APIs? The Intuit developer information is very confusing; it is mainly oriented towards extending the desktop version of Quickbooks or  developing apps to publish in Intuit's app store.

Have you successfully created a web or other service-side app that was able to pull data to or from QB Online?

Answer (score 3):

If you're building a one-off application, the QuickBooks Online qbXML gateway is the way to go. It's a pretty simple POST-your-XML-requests-over-HTTP sort of interface that gives you access to a large chunk (but not all) of the functionality within QuickBooks Online.

If you're building a SaaS application, then you should be looking at the Intuit Partner Platform instead. It sounds like you're building a one-off app for your company, so we'll focus on that:

If you look on [my QuickBooks integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition#example_qbxml_for_online_edition) there are some example qbXML requests to show you how to sign on, and how to POST qbXML requests to the QuickBooks servers.

You don't specify a language, but if you're using PHP, then try out my open-source [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/php_devkit) (look at docs/example_online_edition.php and docs/example_raw_online_edition.php in the .zip nightly builds).

You'll want to use the [QuickBooks OSR](http://dev.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/OSR/OnscreenRef.html) for qbXML reference. The QuickBooks SDK also has 40+ pages *specifically about QuickBooks Online Edition* that you should probably review.

The [Intuit Developer Forums](https://idnforums.intuit.com/) are another good resource.

Comment: Thanks! We are still discussing internally to decide what to do, but this is some helpful info.